# How to build fromMap and toMap for predefined classes in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to build fromMap and toMap methods for predefined classes in flutter. Check the below code.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';
import 'package:time_machine/time_machine.dart';

class Session {
final TableCalendar startDate;
final LocalDate localDate;
final DateTime dateTime;
    Session({
        required this.startDate,
        required this.localDate,
        required this.dateTime,
    });
}
```

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58199782/please-help-me-understand-frommap-and-tomap-from-this-code

Comment: Simplest way to do with quicktype.io!  Just pass the json response, it will generate you the whole thing!